# android parse xml with a lot of node with equals name

Tags: android, xml, nodes

i've got an xml like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>id</key>
    <string><![CDATA[ 1 ]]></string>
    <key>posizione</key>
    <string><![CDATA[ 1 ]]></string>
    <key>id_parent</key>
    <string><![CDATA[ 0 ]]></string>
    <key>prodotto</key>
    <string><![CDATA[ Caduta temporanea ]]></string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>id</key>
    <string><![CDATA[ 1 ]]></string>
    <key>posizione</key>
    <string><![CDATA[ 1 ]]></string>
    <key>id_parent</key>
    <string><![CDATA[ 0 ]]></string>
    <key>prodotto</key>
    <string><![CDATA[ Caduta temporanea ]]></string>
</dict>
```

how can i parse this to obtain a simple string for each ?
usually, i use this method: [Android xml with cdata return nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527477/android-xml-with-cdata-return-nothing)
but with this, i obtain only the first couple of

can someone help me?

Comment: The number of <key> tag is fixed?

Comment: yes it is. also the <string> is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below Code for Parse Same Tag Using Dom Parser.

```
public class DomParserSampleActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ScrollView mScrView1 = new ScrollView(this);

        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(1);

        /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
        TextView id[];
        TextView published[];
        TextView content[];
        TextView title[];

        TextView mediacontent[];
        TextView mediathumbnail[];

        try {
            URL url = new URL("URL_OF_XML_FILE");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("dict");

            /** Assign textview array length by arraylist size */
            firstkey = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            secondkey = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            thirdkey = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            fourthkey = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                firstkey[i] = new TextView(this);
                secondkey[i] = new TextView(this);
                thirdkey[i] = new TextView(this);
                fourthkey[i] = new TextView(this);

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

                NodeList keyList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("key");
                Element keyElement = (Element) keyList.item(0);
                keyList = keyElement.getChildNodes();
                firstkey[i].setText("key is = "
                        + ((Node) keyList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                secondkey[i].setText("key is = "
                        + ((Node) keyList.item(1)).getNodeValue());
                thirdkey[i].setText("key is = "
                        + ((Node) keyList.item(2)).getNodeValue());
                fourthkey[i].setText("key is = "
                        + ((Node) keyList.item(3)).getNodeValue());

                layout.addView(firstkey[i]); 
                layout.addView(secondkey[i]); 
                layout.addView(thirdkey[i]); 
                layout.addView(fourthkey[i]);    
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /** Set the layout view to display */

        mScrView1.addView(layout);
        setContentView(mScrView1);
    }
}
```